# Editext Focuse in android

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

In my application i'm using edit text view in exapandable listview.
When i'm trying to add text in edit text the focus of editext automatically changing.
i'm not able to put text in edit text properly.
what should i do?

edit text xml-

```
    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editDetails"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="3"      
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer-
this is working for me now by adding below line in activity tag-

```
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xml try this also in your EditText

```
android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords
```